# Blazor Wasm HttpClient Authorisation header not providing claims

Tags: http, http-headers, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've upgraded a Blazor Wasm app to .Net 6, by creating new projects and then added MS Identity (not Identity Server) from Chris Sainty's blog.  Authorisation looks ok & the user can logon.  However the claims are not available to the api controller.  This is because it looks like the Authorisation header is not being set for the http client call.  If I explicitly set the DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization to the jwt token then I get the claims in the controller ok.  I therefore assume the issue is in how I setup the http client (I thought ApiAuthenticationStateProvider would have done this).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The relevant parts are:

Client: AuthService:

```
public async Task<LoginResponse> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    loginModel.BaskeyKey = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>(LocalStorageConstants.BasketKey);

    var loginAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginModel);

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/Login", new StringContent(loginAsJson,
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    var loginResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoginResponse>(
            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(),
            new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return loginResult;
    }

    await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync("authToken", loginResult.Token);

    ((ApiAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(loginModel.Email);

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", loginResult.Token);

    _basketStateService.SetBasket(loginResult.LoginResponseDto.BasketDto);

    return loginResult;
}
```

Server Startup:

```
            builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
                {
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LTDbContext>();


            builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

            });

            var jwtSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt");

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
            {
                auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        ValidIssuer = jwtSettings["JwtIssuer"],
                        ValidAudience = jwtSettings["JwtAudience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings["JwtSecurityKey"]))
                    };

                    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
                });
```

and client setup for httpClient (I need an authorised & unauthorised client - I think)

```
   builder.Services.AddHttpClient(AuthConstants.Auth, client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
            });

    builder.Services.AddHttpClient(AuthConstants.NoAuth,
                    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
            
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => 
                sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(AuthConstants.Auth));
```

and Client - ApiAuthenticationStateProvider

```
  public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var savedToken = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(
                new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);
 
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
    }


    public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string email)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(
            new ClaimsIdentity(new[] 
            { 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email) 
            },
            "apiauth"
            ));

        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
```

Comment: If it helps anyone, I'm going with setting the Authorization header for now, after Creating the HttpClient:  
        var savedToken = await LocalStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);

Comment: Setting the header IS the way to go. Maybe take a look at this [video](https://youtu.be/2c4p6RGtkps).

Comment: thanks @Grizzlly, good to hear.  I'll go through the video too.